# Masters in computer science vs masters in cyber security

Tags: masters

I recently graduated with a degree in computer science and really enjoyed it. However in my last semester I took a cyber security elective class and found it very interesting, especially with the things going on in the world in reference to cyber security. I'm currently working full time and am strongly considering going back to school in the fall (I'd only be out of school one semester between undergrad and grad school) I would continue to work because they have a great tuition reimbursement program.

My question is, I really enjoy and find cyber security interesting, but I feel it's somewhat limiting myself to the cyber security field if I get a master's in that. I know I could still work in other computing areas and use what I learn in those areas, but I would kind of feel like I wasted my time if I'm not using my knowledge on a regular basis.

On the other hand, the university I'd be applying to has a cyber security concentration in the computer science master's program, but it's only about 1/3rd as many classes as the cyber security program. This way I'd have a competency in cyber security, but the program would allow me to have other roles and jobs, and I'd feel like I was still using what I learned.

I'm not planning on going for a PhD (not any time in the next decade or two at least) and have no real experience in security except for the class I took my last semester.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working in the field of software security for over 4 years and had multiple interactions with security analysts working in cyber security labs. From their collective opinion, a computer science degree is just as effective as a more "specialist" cyber security degree. This is because they both have roughly the same CS foundation and the few extra security-oriented classes won't make a huge difference after 1-2 years of industry experience. In fact, I have encountered multiple CS graduates who are more successfull in the security industry than the cyber security graduates. This is of course, anecdotal.

Comment: Plus, if you do CS, you'll be certain of getting, and being able to demonstrate, a strong CS foundation. // There would not be anything to prevent you from taking extra courses in a particular area, such as cyber security.

Comment: @aparente001 I agree